# Special characters getting replaced by place holders

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my ADF if I'm ingesting data with copy data activity it takes almost all special characters but it does not take the curly quote and £ symbols and just gets replaced by placeholders like "?" . what changes can I make so that I can ingest and preview the data as is?

Also my configuration is as follows:

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQQL.png)

I have a sentence with characters £ and ‘ and after copy data when I preview data I'm getting the "?"  as a place holder. But I want the £ and ‘ as is in the data and not be replaced with a place holder

Comment: If ADF doesn't read characters correctly, it might be an issue with the file encoding. Try to change the encoding on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The above configurations will work for you. I have tried with below sample data in a csv file:

```
firstname,lastname
R£k$‘esh,G“ovi’nd$ula'
lad$d“',Ch£“nna'$
£“£$££,“'$
“£“$“,££“££'
r$,$££s
```

I kept the same configurations as yours.

[image]

**Data preview:**

[image]

> when I preview data I'm getting the "?" as a place holder

Sometimes, the preview might give the result like this. So, first copy the data to a sample file using copy activity and recheck again with another dataset after publishing everything. Also, try with `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding if it does not work.